# C++ Function Template, Undefined Symbol for Architecture

Tags: c++, templates

Can someone please explain to me why the following won't compile?, and hopefully the obvious thing that I have missed...

**functions.hpp:**

```
template<typename T> string vector_tostr(std::vector<T> v);
```

**functions.cpp:**

```
template<typename T> string vector_tostr(std::vector<T> v){
    std::stringstream ss;
    std::string thestring = "";
    if(v.size() > 0){
        ss << "[";
        for(size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++){
            if(i != 0)
                ss << " ";
            ss << v[i];
        }
        ss << "]";
        thestring = ss.str();
    }
    return thestring;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "functions.hpp"
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
   vector<int> thevector;
   thevector.push_back(1);
   thevector.push_back(2);

   string result = vector_tostr(thevector);
   //I have also tried vector_tostr<int>(thevector)
}
```

The cryptic error I am getting as follows:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:   "std::basic_string, std::allocator >
>   vector_tostr(std::vector >)", referenced
>   from:
>         _main in main.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status make: *** [main] Error 1

Comment: OS ? google search shows it may be issue of not including libraries on apple's OS

Comment: Using Mac os X, compiling with g++-mp-4.8 (need openmp for other stuff)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not allowed to seperate the declaration and definition of a templated function in the same way that you would a normal function (declaration in '.hpp' file, definition in '.cpp' file). There are a couple of ways you can get around that.

You can declare AND define the function in the same place in the header file.

OR

You could try this, in a file called `functions.inl`:

```c++
template<typename T> 
inline string vector_tostr(std::vector<T> v){
    std::stringstream ss;
    std::string thestring = "";
    if(v.size() > 0){
        ss << "[";
        for(size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++){
            if(i != 0)
                ss << " ";
            ss << v[i];
        }
        ss << "]";
        thestring = ss.str();
    }
    return thestring;
}
```

Then, at the end of the header file (`functions.hpp`), type this in:

```c++
#include "functions.inl"
```

`.inl` is the file extension for the inline header file. You can use this to seperate the declaration
and definition of templated functions.

Comment: Is `.inl` common? Never heard of it before. Why not just define it in the header? Or name the second "header" a `.h`?

Comment: The `.inl` extension is common primarily in Visual C++. It's considered good programming practice to separate the declaration and definition of a function in C++.

Comment: Yet you start with "You are not allowed to seperate the declaration and definition...". This is quite misleading!

Comment: @juanchopanza Fixed the misleading part of the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Templates are instantiated in compile time. What the compiler does is create one overloaded method  *for each template argument value* that is used in the code. For example, using `int` and `double` as template argument will create **two** overloaded methods from the same definition, only vary in argument type. So compiler must be able to see the **definition** while compiling. You can do this in several ways

1. Fully defined in header
2. Defined in for ex. .impl file and include it in the declaring header
3. Explicitly instantiated with *template parameter* in a .cpp file, in that case only the instantiated versions can be used.

Answer (score 3):

You need to have the implementation of the function template visible where it's used. Otherwise, the compiler doesn't know how to instantiate the function given a type.

Put the function definition in `functions.hpp`. There is no use of `functions.cpp`.